# eclipse luna windows 8 android google map ERROR

Tags: android, eclipse-luna

I have a problem with eclipse luna windows 8 -64 bit, i install the sdk and I am trying to have a google map example, but when I run the project eclipse luna stop working.

I tried different emulators same problem(i have tried eclipse Juno same problem).

Any normal android project works properly.

Comment: You need to post the output of the logcat and relevant code. It is probably related to your project and not your IDE or OS

Comment: Android Studio and solve your errors.

Comment: Also, check the eclipse logs and add relevant parts here, if it really is Eclipse that stops working. "Stop working" is also to generic. Does it crash? Hang? Or is your application in an infinite loop causing eclipse to hang?

Comment: thank you .Now i change my environment to android studio

Answer (score 0):

Google play services are not defined in emulators, so better is to run your code on device.
Also be sure you have include Google play services libs in your project.